# Select from or filter in an IEnumerable in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is the model:

```
public class PolicyDetail
{
    public Policy Policy { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Insured> Insured { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Risk> Risk { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Construction> Construction { get; set; }
}
```

Construction just looks like this:

```
public class Construction
{
    public int ConstructionID { get; set; }
    public string ConstructionType { get; set; }
}
```

And in the DB, there are only 4 rows.  It's basically an enum.

And within Risk is this property:

```
public int ConstructionID { get; set; }
```

Before sending the model to the view, we fill up each object within PolicyDetail, where Insured and Risk are children of Policy.  Construction is loaded up every time with all four of it's rows.

So, in the model, we are listing off all the Risks. When I get to Construction, I want to display the selected Construction Type.

As expected, this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Risk)
{
    ... other items in Risk
    @item.ConstructionID
}
```

Just displays the ID.  1, 3, 4 etc.  I'm trying to write a lynq query to extract the ConstructionType from Model.Construction based on item.ConstructionID. I'm playing around with things like:

```
@Model.Construction.Select(a => a.ConstructionID == item.ConstructionID).First()
```

But nothing I've tried has worked so far.

**EDIT:**

To be more clear, this is what I want:

```
SELECT ConstructionType FROM Model.Construction WHERE ConstructionID = type.ConstructionID
```

**Answer:**

@Model.Construction.First(a => a.ConstructionID == item.ConstructionID).ConstructionType

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve.  Could you include a bit of sample data and the output you are wanting?

Comment: _It's basically an enum._ - So why no make it an enum? If there is only one `Construction` associated with a `Policy`, then why does you model have property `IEnumerable<Construction>`?

Comment: @BJ Myers - see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@Model.Construction.First(a => a.ConstructionID == item.ConstructionID).ConstructionType;
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  This gives me something to go from.  But I as is, I get this error: 'Construction' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Construction' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Model.Construction.First(a => a.ConstructionID == item.ConstructionID).ConstructionType

Comment: You got me 95% there.  Thanks!